# Javascript - Issue with sort function on Opera 11.60 and IE 8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, sorting, opera

I am trying to sort objects by there properties. I have a problem on Opera and IE with my function. Till now, I have debugged the problem on Opera at this stage:

1. Open "Opera browser" and press cntr+shift+i. Choose the console.
2. Pass this code in the console and press shift+enter.

   ```
   var DataArray=["Other","Attitude","Attitude","Delivery/timings","General   Performance","Personal Planning","Other"]
   DataArray=DataArray.sort(function(a,b)
   {
       return a<b;
    });

   JSON.stringify(DataArray);
   ```

You should get correct result like this:

> > ["Personal Planning","Other","Other","General Performance","Delivery/timings","Attitude","Attitude"]

1. Now change the sort function in this way a>b like this and press enter+shift to exucute it.

   ```
   var DataArray=["Other","Attitude","Attitude","Delivery/timings","General   Performance","Personal Planning","Other"]
   DataArray=DataArray.sort(function(a,b)
   {
       return a>b;
   });
   JSON.stringify(DataArray);
   ```

My result is:

> > ["Attitude","Delivery/timings","Attitude","General   Performance","Other","Other","Personal Planning"]

Note the first, the second and the third value?What is going on?

If you execute this in the console "Attitude"="Attitude" it returns true...

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
And the part with the IE:

CODE:

```
 var DataArray=['Other','Attitude','Attitude','Delivery/timings','General    Performance','Personal Planning','Other'];

 DataArray=DataArray.sort(function(a,b)
{
     return a<b;
 });

prompt('',DataArray);
```

Result(correct):Personal Planning,Other,Other,General Performance,Attitude,Attitude,Delivery/timings

CODE:

var DataArray=['Other','Attitude','Attitude','Delivery/timings','General Performance','Personal Planning','Other'];

```
    DataArray=DataArray.sort(function(a,b)
    {
        return a>b;
    });

    prompt('',DataArray);
```

RESULT (incorrect): Attitude,Attitude,Other,Delivery/timings,General Performance,Other,Personal Planning

SOLUTION:

```
sortableArray=sortableArray.sort(function(a,b)
                {
                    if(a.Category>b.Category)
                    {
                        return 1;
                    }

                    if(a.Category<b.Category)
                    {
                        return -1;
                    }

                    return 0;

                });
```

To sort in descending way the data use reverse() function.

Thank you for the help. Especially to @nnnnnn

Comment: Probably not related, but `sort()` will sort an array in place - you don't need to assign it back to the variable.

Comment: This is true, but in my real situation i am using this to sort objects by property:

sortableArray=sortableArray.sort(function(a,b)
     {
      return a.Category>b.Category;
     });

I have just debugged the things to this.

Comment: No problem with IE8, the result is: `["Attitude", "Attitude", "Delivery/timings", "General Performance", "Other", "Other", "Personal Planning"]`. (You can test with this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4v4Th/)).

Comment: Please post the *real* code and RTFM before you post. The `sort` method is well-documented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't a problem with any particular browser, it is a problem with not having read the [`.sort()` function documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). The callback you pass to `.sort()` is not supposed to return a boolean, it is supposed to return a number that is:

- negative if a comes before b
- 0 if a equals b
- positive if a comes after b

Comment: Thank you very much. I have thought that this is a browser problem because in webkit browsers and firefox I sort the data right.

Comment: I think you'll find that in the other browsers you were getting the expected result more by luck than anything. It definitely would _not_ work for all cases if you just returned a boolean.

Answer (score 4):

Your sorting function returns a boolean value, while it should return an integer. While `1` can be confused as `true` and `0` as `false`, this shouldn't be something that you rely your code logic on. The function should have 3 return cases :

- `< 0` if `a > b`
- `> 0` if `a < b`
- `== 0` if `a == b`

So you should use sort your array like this :

```
  DataArray = DataArray.sort(function(a,b){
      return a>b ? 1 : a<b ? -1 : 0;          
  });
```

#### Here's a [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rmqAu/).

Comment: `DataArray.sort(function (a, b) { return a - b; });` Of course, in that case you can simply omit the sort function.

Comment: @PointedEars - the `a-b` technique is a nice shortcut only for _numeric data_.

Comment: @nnnnnn Correct, or for data convertible to `Number`.